# Proving Chebyshev inequality

Tags: probability, probability-theory, random-variables, bernoulli-numbers

Let $\xi_1,...,\xi_n$ be independent and equally distributed Bernoulli random variables. Also let $\mathbb{P}(\xi_i=1)=p,$  $\mathbb{P}(\xi_i=-1)=1-p$ where $i=1,...,n.$ Prove that 
$$\mathbb{P} \Bigg( \Big|  \frac{\xi_1+\xi_2+...+\xi_n}{n}-(2p-1)\geq \varepsilon      \Big| \Bigg) \leq 2 e^{\frac{-n\varepsilon^2}{4}}.$$

So I think I should use  Chebyshev's inequality $\mathbb{P}(\xi\geq\varepsilon)\leq \frac{\mathbb{E}\xi}{\varepsilon}$. But I don't know how to start. How to begin this proving?

Comment: Hint: Bernoulli plus Bernoulli is..

Comment: $\mathbb{P}(\xi_1+\xi_2+...+\xi_n)=\mathbb{P}(\xi_1,\xi_2,...,\xi_n)$?

Comment: No. A sum of independent Bernoulli variables follows what distribution?

Comment: @SeanRoberson Not sure where you're going there. If your end goal is to suggest using Chernoff/Hoeffding on a Binomial, this may be a bit contrived (the exercise is essentially asking to prove those for the specific case of a sum of Rademacher r.v.'s)

Comment: Also, to the OP: what you wrote as Chebyshev's is Markov's inequality.